# Tracking App Usage

Tags: jquery, cordova, statistics, tracking, parse-platform

I have an app built with Phontgap + Jquery that performs calculative functions for the user.  I'd like to track how many times the "Calculate" button has been used.  For this I was thinking about using Parse.com.  So it would look like this:

1) Query the App usage %D value from Parse.com database.
2) App Splashscreen reads "%D calculations have been performed!"
3) App sends update (%D+1+ value to Parse.com. New vale is saved.

Is there a better way to do this?  I realize this creates two different queries and I think there has to be a better way to do this. However, my current method is very simple only requiring a few lines of code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [localstorage API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) that you could use to track how many times the button is clicked.

There is an example of this that we use in mobile-spec to test Cordova: https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/blob/master/storage/index.html

Have a look at the example. Every time that particular page is accessed, the counter is incremented and the new value is displayed. If you close the app and then open it again, the counter will persist. If you remove the app and reinstall it, the counter will naturally be reset.

Seems like you could pretty easily adapt this example to count how many times your button is clicked.